# How to extract Int16 from Data in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I've been trying to access the data in a BLE service characteristic value for a few days now. I thought figuring out how to translate the [Temperature Sensor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html) example to Swift would be helpful, but I get stuck at the same spot.

How do I translate the Obj-C:

```
- (CGFloat) maximumTemperature
{
    CGFloat result  = NAN;
    int16_t value   = 0;

    if (maxTemperatureCharacteristic) {
        [[maxTemperatureCharacteristic value] getBytes:&value length:sizeof (value)];
        result = (CGFloat)value / 10.0f;
    }
    return result;
}
```

to Swift 3?

Instead of a CGFloat, in my code I am using the struct:

```
struct MPUData {
    let x: Int16
    let y: Int16
    let z: Int16
}
```

and am receiving an 8 byte value from the characteristic with the first six being the x, y, and z components (i.e `0x0D0E0F00` where `x = 0x0D`, `y = 0x0E`, `z = 0x0F` and the last byte is unused)

I have no idea how to traverse the bits and store them as their Int16 values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `withUnsafeBytes`:

```
//Assuming `data` as `someCharacteristic.value!`
//Create 4 Int16 data in little endian
let data = Data(bytes: [0x0D, 0, 0x0E, 0, 0x0F, 0, 0, 0])

struct MPUData {
    let x: Int16
    let y: Int16
    let z: Int16
}
let mpuData = data.withUnsafeBytes {(int16Ptr: UnsafePointer<Int16>)->MPUData in
    MPUData(x: Int16(littleEndian: int16Ptr[0]),
        y: Int16(littleEndian: int16Ptr[1]),
        z: Int16(littleEndian: int16Ptr[2]))
}
print(mpuData.x,mpuData.y,mpuData.z) //->13 14 15
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that I'd stick it in a init?(data: Data) constructor and return nil if the you don't get the expected buffer size, because thats usually a sign that you have the wrong data: guard data.count == MemoryLayout<Int16>.size * 3 else {return nil}

Comment: Looks like this will work. Hopefully I'll get a chance to test/vote up today.